# Prove or disprove if $f:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ is a differentiable function and $Df=0$ then $f$ is constant

Tags: calculus

Prove or disprove if $f:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ is a differentiable function and $Df=0$ then $f$ is constant function

From my understanding, $Df$ is just the linearly transformation of $f$, so $Df=0$ doesn't mean that $f$ doesn't change at all, but I can't find any counter example for this.

Comment: Try using mean value theorem.

Comment: are you saying it's true?

Comment: "$Df$ is just the linearly transformation of $f$" ???? $Df(x_0)$ is the best lineat approximation of $f$ near $x_0$. What is "the linearly transformation"?

Comment: Is true in this case (connected domain).

Comment: linearly transformation is also know as vector multiplication.

Comment: "linearly transformation is also know as vector multiplication" ???????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: each $n \times m$ matrix can be identified with a linear transformation from $\mathbb R^m$ to $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: Matrix product $\ne$ vector product.

Comment: ok, I used the wrong word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Df$ is the mape $a \mapsto Df_a$. Forall $a$  in $\Bbb R^m$, we know that $Df_a$ is linear map from $\Bbb R^m$ to $\Bbb R^n$

To answer your question you can consider $a,b \in \Bbb R^m$  and  prove that $f(a)=f(b)$.

To  do  this  Let : $$\begin{array}{lcrcl}g &:& [0,1]& \to & \Bbb R^n
\\ &&t&\mapsto&f((1-t)a+tb)\end{array}$$ for all $t \in[0,1]$, then  we  have:

$$(\forall t \in [0,1])\quad g'(t)=Df_{((1-t)a+tb)}(b-a)=0$$

That gives $g$  is constant in $[0,1]$  and $g(0)=g(1)$ then $f(a)=f(b)$ (since $g(0)=f(a)$  and  $g(1)=f(b)$.)

Comment: may I have a question, you let $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb R^n$ but $[0,1] \in \mathbb R$ not $\mathbb R^m$. is it just one dimension but not all $m$ dimension?

Comment: we have using one dimension property to prove that $f(a)=f(b)$ using the mape $g$ who depends on $a,b \in \Bbb R^m$.

Answer (score 0):

For one varaible, if $\frac {df}{dx}=0$ then $\frac {f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=f^{'}(c)=0$ by mean value so $f(x)=f(y)$.

Now,Let $F:R^n\to R^m$ then $\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}|_a=0$ since $dF=0$ where it denotes directional derivatives of $F$. From first argument $F$ is constant on given direction.Since it is true for all $\vec u$, $F$ is constant.